# Mercurial not working after TortoiseHg update

Tags: windows-7, mercurial

I recently updated TortoiseHg to 2.0.3 (with Mercurial 1.8.2). After updating, Mercurial no longer works via the command line (Windows 7 x64), but does work via the TortoiseHg GUI. Trying to use any Hg commands via the command line results in the error message `'hg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'`

I'm guessing I need to make some change to a setting in TortoiseHg or Windows 7 so that Windows will recognize `hg` commands, but I'm not sure what that change is. I am very new to using Hg - I installed it a few months ago (thus the need for an update), but only recently started using it.

Comment: It sounds like your PATH doesn't include the location of `hg` although `thg` has a default location coded into it.

Comment: @msw The last entry in my PATH is `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\`, which contains `hg.exe`. FWIW, `thg` doesn't do anything from the command line either.

Comment: Do a search for hg.* under c:\ and see what you come up with.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Nothing directly under C:\. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I meant including all sub-folders, a recursive search. See where you have either `hg.exe`, `hg.bat` or `hg.cmd`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TortoiseHg v2.X.X no longer uses the `hg` command, instead try `thg`.

Your install path might be different, but typically thg.CMD exists at:

`C:/Program Files/TortoiseHg/bin/`

If you've installed Mercurial independent of TortoiseHg you may still have access to the `hg` executable, but most people just install TortoiseHg and take the associated copy of Mercurial, in which case you would need to use the `thg` commands.

Comment: I've tried that, but get the same error message: `'thg' is not recognzied as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @tnorthcutt Ahhh - I see that in your comemnts, now.

Comment: @tnorthcutt try the path I've added in my answer, above. `thg` is actually a *.CMD file and should be located here for Win7

Comment: @dls I don't have a `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\bin` directory. There is a `thg.exe` file in `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg` however. I think I"ll try installing Mercurial itself and see what happens.

Comment: I tried installing Mercurial separately, and it correctly added `C:\Program Files\Mercurial`\ to the PATH variable as expected. However, typing in `hg` or `thg` at the command line still do not work.

Comment: @tnorthcutt You are correct, `thg.exe` shows up at `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg`. My bin directory content must be from somewhere else. That being said, I might try doing a complete uninstall of both Mercurial and TortoiseHg, and then re-installing TortoiseHg and doing a re-start. I can't explain why it wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: For some reason, uninstalling, restarting, and then installing caused it to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: And I should note that `hg` functions as expected (typing `hg` by itself produces a list of commands), and `thg` starts the TortoiseHg Workbench.

Comment: @tnorthcutt: I see you've already resolved the problem; see http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2658 and http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2673 for some background information about the cause (read from bottom to top).

Comment: @Niall C. - thanks very much for the background information. Nice to get some education on it.

Comment: Wasn't the `hg.cmd` file dropped in later versions of the TortoiseHg x64 installation? At least on my machine I no longer have that file.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this by removing the "/" at the end of the Path:

From

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\"
```

to

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg"
```

Comment: This worked for me. Red Gate Source control was unable to link a database and failed with the error "hg is not recognized as an internal or external command". Doing this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the leading quotation mark - the PATH variable contained:

```
...;"C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg
```

and I changed it to

```
...;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg
```

to make it work with Red-Gate SQL Source control.