# TortoiseHg: ‘hg’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm unable to find the command line tools in Mercurial-TortoiseHg version 2.7.2. I checked for hg.exe file and it is present at **C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg** path but whenever I try running the command it fails and throws the error :

‘hg’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have also added it to the windows PATH= ; C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg.

Not sure what else to look for. Please help.

Comment: Is the new PATH setting visible in your command line console (e.g. with 'set PATH')? If it isn't, try again with a new command line console. Environment variable changes are read when the console is started. Any changes won't be visible in consoles that were started before the change.

Comment: Yes, I've restarted the command line a couple of times and checked that as well. The path shows correctly but again the "hg" command doesn't run.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Notes:

- As mentioned in "[Mercurial not working after TortoiseHg update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687685/6309)", TortoiseHg v2.X.X no longer uses the `hg` command, [but rather `thg`](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.8/intro.html?highlight=thg).
  That means your `PATH` might not be updated properly to reference hg.exe of TortoiseHg.
- to update your `PATH`, make sure *not* add any extra space:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg
```

(no space between '`;`' and '`C:\...`')

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399307/tortoisehg-hg-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable/16399548?noredirect=1#comment23509088_16399548) by the [OP Sowmya Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1596103/sowmya-guru), if you modify the user environment variable, a restart (or at least a new DOS windows) is necessary.

Comment: Yes, the space was the issue! :) And also needs a restart for environmental variables to apply. Thanks a lot. Very helpful.

Comment: Also if both hg.exe and thg.exe files are present then both hg and thg commands can run in the command line not necessarily only thg.

Comment: @SowmyaGuru very true: once the `PATH` is correctly set, any executable within that `PATH` is available.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my answer related to vanilla Mercurial install (not 'TortoiseHg') as it was the first page in search results, my solution was to use the 'Mercurial-3.4 (64-bit msi)' installer instead of the 'Mercurial-3.4 (64-bit exe)' from [this page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download).